# how should I delete non numbers in list use prolog

Tags: list, filter, prolog

I should remove all elements of List that are not a number greater than number. I can solve it just for numbers. but when the list has some symbolic how should I delete.this is my code

```
greater_nrs_only( X, List, Ans) :-
    greater_nrs_only( X, List, Ans, [] ), !.

greater_nrs_only( _, [], Ans, Ans).
greater_nrs_only( X, [H | Tail], Ans, Acc ) :-
    (
        ( H < X, NewEl = [] )
        ;
        ( H >= X, NewEl = [H] )
    ),
    append( Acc, NewEl, NewAcc ),
    greater_nrs_only( X, Tail, Ans, NewAcc).
```

and ?- greater_nrs_only(6, [ ], X).
is false

Comment: If I run this locally, I get `X = []`.

Comment: but when I run with greater_nrs_only(6,[3,a,b,-1],X) just error

Comment: yes, since `6 < a`, errors, since it is non-sensical to compare these. You can check if it is a number with `number(H)`.

Answer (score 2):

The reason this will error is because `H` is not per se a number, so comparing `6` with `a` for example will raise an error. You can use [**`number/1`** [swi-doc]](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=number/1) to check if something is a number.

Instead of doing filtering manually, you can also work with [**`include/3`** [swi-doc]](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=include/3), which filters the list for items that satisfy a given predicate:

```
greater_than(X, Y) :-
    number(Y),
    X < Y.

greater_nrs_only(X, L, R) :-
    include(greater_than(X), L, R).
```

Comment: thanks! it works but I should change X <= Y to Y > X.

Comment: @zhangrui: you probably mean `=<`? Otherwise you get items that are smaller than `X`.

Comment: yep but I solved it actually I should use X < Y then it works.